# html page layout, content div height fills all remaining space

Tags: html, css

can't get working layout as I want for the page I am creating for my portfolio website.
I have header with navigation(fixed size div).
then I have content div
and I have footer

```
<div>header</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>footer</div>
```

I want footer be fixed size, let say 200px, fixed always to the bottom of page. but content should fill all remaining space from header to footer. so that content div height would depend on windows height. By changing height only content div would change size.

Comment: Well, there are plenty of questions and answers on SO that address this kind of layout. Only if you searched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: Flagged as dupe of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flex makes it easy:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  /* eventually : min-height: xx ; to avoid main to be squeezed down to zero  in between header and footer */
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  }
.main {
  flex:1;/* fills remaining space */
  overflow:auto;/* comes handy */
  background:lightgray;/* see me */
  }
  div {
  padding:1em;/* whatever */
  }
```

```html
<div>header of any height</div>
<div class="main">content</div>
<div>footer of any height</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #9f0d0d;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    min-height: 5%;
}

    header :first-child {
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
    }

article {
    top: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    position: fixed;
}

footer {
    top: 95%;
    min-height: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #9f0d0d;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

    footer :first-child {
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
    }

.centre {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centre">
  <header>Header</header>
  <article>Remaining space</article>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tested this solution, but here header and footer are not fixed size and it changes when page is resized.

Comment: yes. you can replace the values according to your need. the values in there, are the way I wanted them. basically, the solution is to give you the general idea on what properties to move them to the spot you wanted.

Comment: it is based on a responsive concept I used in a mobile web app. everything resizes according to the screen size of the device. declare min-height:200px; if you like your footer to stay minimum height. you can also adjust all other properties according to your hearts content.